# How to repeatedly call the same function in a process pool in Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Considering the following code, is there some more pythonish way to do that?

Storing every process in a list to then call another function (`result()`) in each of those process seems bad design. Even more so if what I need is a list of results, like what `Executor.map()` does, but since the function doesn't have parameters (or they could be the same in all calls) I cannot use `map()` do it.

```
import random
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def random_computation():
    x = random.randint(1,1000)
    y = random.randint(1,1000)
    z = random.randint(1,1000)
    return x * y / z

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        processes = []
        for _ in range(1000):
            processes.append(executor.submit(random_computation))
        results = [p.result() for p in processes]
```

Comment: The title says "call the same function", the description says "call another function". Why?

Comment: I meant the call to `p.result()`.